# How to include parameters in url using nodejs+jade?

Tags: node.js, express, pug

In jade I have two hyper links that both jump to same page, for example:

```
a(href='/signup')#create-account Create Student Account
a(href='/signup')#create-admin Create Teacher Account
```

If I want a variable send to '/signup' url and do some processing using that variable, what should I do?

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on whether you will make your app to be RESTful or not.
Saying you would like to be Restful. 
To create an admin you should make a POST to the url /admin.
Respectively to create an account you should post to the url /account.

This is if admin and account are different resources. If it is the same recourse you should post to the original recourse and with the posted data, make the decision what to save where.

jade form:

```
  div.loginbox
    form(name="login", action="/signup", method="post")
      input(type="checkbox" name="admin")
      input(type="text", name="user")
      input(type="password", name="pass")
      input(type="submit", value="login")
```

Comment: Let's say if I want both of them post to /signup, then can I post a variable like type='student' to that url?admin and account here are same recourse here

Comment: i edited, the reply and added the jade form which post to the signup url. I added a checkbox to decide if it is an admin or not. Obviously it is a very bad way to tell admins from simple users, but as it is an example i think its ok.